# cakePHP and conditions on deep association

Tags: cakephp, join, associations

The data structure is:

```
tenants {id, ...}
contracts {id, active, tenant_id, ...}
debts {id, contract_id, ...}
```

the desired data is:

tenants list, filtered by contracts and debts.
conditions:

- contract must be active.
- tenant has debts

keep in mind:

- tenant has many contracts
- contracts has many debts
- contain won't help, since it will not filter the tenants.

My idea is to manually create the joins, and add filters to them. but how exactly?

my questions:

1. How can i do it with native cake?
2. how would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put all this logic on models.
For each tables create a model (You can use the Cake Bake tools or write it by yourself).

```
class Tenant extends AppModel{
  public $hasMany = array('Contract'); // feel free to ajust settings 
}

class Contract extends AppModel{
  public $belongsTo = array('Tenant');
  public $hasMany = array('Debt');
}

class Debt extends AppModel{
  public $belongsTo = array('Contract');
}
```

Now you can use on your Tenant controller something like that :

```
function action(){
  $this->Tenant->recursive = 2;
  $all_contracts = $this->Tenant->find('all');
}
```

But that solution is not the best, you can wrap this logic into model's method.

```
class Tenant extends AppModel
{
  public $hasMany = array('Contract');

  public function contracts($is_active = true) {
    /*
        Create your own logic here, you have many solutions to retrieve data like 
        load the containable behaviors, create a custom find method, custom query ...

        Do stuff here not in controller action.
    */
    $this->Behaviors->load('Containable');
    $this->contain(array(
        'Contract' => array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'active' => $is_active
            ),
            'Debt'
        )
    ));
    return $this->find('all');
  }   
}

class Contract extends AppModel{

  public $belongsTo = array('Tenant');
  public $hasMany = array('Debt');


}

class Debt extends AppModel{
  public $belongsTo = array('Contract');
```

}

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#creating-custom-find-types

Comment: thanks, but it's not a solution for my problem.
contain is a set of queries that executed AFTER the list of tenants is set. but i want to filter the tenants.

Comment: $this->find('all', array('conditions' => array(/* put your filter here */));

Comment: You can't add condition for deep association this way.